# "Мое мнение, что..." Какого типа предложение в первой части СПП?

Tags: синтаксис, сложное-предложение

> Мое мнение, что у вашего высочества никогда не будет такого прекрасного смотрителя дворцовых покоев.

***Мое мнение*** — это часть сложноподчиненного предложения. Вероятно, эта часть является простым предложением. Какой тогда это тип предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “Мое мнение, что…” Какого типа предложение в первой части СПП?

**Двусоставное неполное.** Место сказуемого занимает придаточное сказуемное.

Из [**Грамматики-80:**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2788-2820.html)

> § 2799. **Придаточное предложение может функционировать как сказуемое**.
>   Опорный компонент имеет при этом тенденцию к лексическому ограничению
>   существительными со значением мнения или впечатления.
>
> *Впечатление мое, что нужда большая* (Л. Толст., переписка); ***Мое
>   мнение, что*** многое, очень многое, тут было лишнее (Дост.);
>   *Совершенно ничего нельзя разобрать. Впечатление - что я попал в Китай* (Фед.).
>
> Эта позиция может акцентироваться местоименным словом *такой*:
>   *Впечатление такое, что...; Мое мнение такое, что...*

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но если придаточное предложение здесь функционирует как сказуемое, то можно ли говорить о неполном предложении (если у нас формально есть и подлежащее, и сказуемое)?

Comment: Можно. Так практически всегда и разбирают... (Сейчас убегаю, не могу более подробно...)

Comment: Немного о неполных предложениях. Бывают неполные, в которых и сказуемое, и подлежащее находятся в других предложениях. Что же до сложноподчинённых… В них главные части очень часто бывают неполными. К примеру, в таких предложениях: _**Удивительно,** что он меня не узнал; **Мне кажется,** что он не изменился._ В этих предложениях придаточные замещают отсутствующие подлежащие в главных предложениях. //Примеры взяты из книги Гайсиной "Синтаксис простого предложения в современном русском языке".

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, это диалогически неполное предложение с пропуском сказуемого **такое**.

Идёт диалог:

-А ваше мнение? (пропуск сказуемого **какое**)

— Мое мнение ( **такое**), что у вашего высочества никогда не будет такого прекрасного смотрителя дворцовых покоев.

Comment: По-моему, правильнее говорить  не о пропуске сказуемого "такое"...  Скорее, здесь придаточное замещает сказуемое главного предложения.

Comment: Тогда бы здесь стояло тире, а у автора стоит запятая, значит, он имел в виду придаточное.

Comment: @slava1947 Запятая стоит и союз *что* стоит. Это несовместимо с Вашей версией.

Answer (score 2):

*Моё мнение* - это главное предложение, которое ***выглядит*** как односоставное назывное. К существительному "мнение" относится придаточное определительное (*мнение какое?*), но присоединяется оно не союзным словом ЧТО, как должно быть при односоставном назывном (ср.: Вот дом, что я построил.), - а союзом ЧТО, и присоединяется  как придаточное изъяснительное (*мнение - от мнить*), которое и выражает смысл, заложенный в слове "мнение". Значит, это не односоставное назывное предложение.

Главное предложение информационно и синтаксически недостаточно. При слове "мнение" в главной части не хватает сказуемого.

Ср.:***Оправдалось мое мнение, что в заговорах каждый потерянный даром день дает лишний шанс против заговорщиков и лишний шанс в пользу их врагов!*** [Н. А. Морозов. Повести моей жизни/ По волнам увлечения (1912)] Пример из Нацкорпуса.

**Значит, главное предложение - неполное двусоставное.**

Answer (score 1):

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным вмещающего типа: такие СПП содержат слова, требующие изъяснения.

Например: *Мое мнение состоит в том, что у вашего высочества никогда не будет такого прекрасного смотрителя дворцовых покоев.*

При этом изъясняемые слова могут употребляться **самостоятельно**: *Мое мнение, что у вашего высочества никогда не будет такого прекрасного смотрителя дворцовых покоев.*

Таким образом, в позиции главного предложения находится **не предложение, а  слово** *мнение* (с определением), то есть словосочетание.

Comment: Если слово заменяет предложение, это и есть неполное предложение. По-моему, все на этом сошлись, тем более, что в исходном тексте худ.  произведения это диалог. В официальной науке такие неполные предложения так и называются  - диалогически неполные.

Comment: Здесь слово не заменяет предложение, а находится в позиции главного предложения. Термин "неполное предложение" имеет другое определение: в неполных предложениях  главный член восстанавливается из контекста. Но здесь ничего этого нет. Слово тоже может быть самостоятельной синтаксической единицей, зачем называть его предложением.

Comment: Что-то Вы меня совсем запутали. То, что это неполное предложение, это абсолютно точно. Придаточное изъяснительное часто относится к неполным предложениям или слову в предложении, но никак не к слову как самостоятельной синт. единице, это тогда должно быть слово-предложение или назывное, у нас не тот случай. А о каком  СПП с придаточным изъяснительным вмещающего типа Вы говорите? Не знаю такого Есть только союзные слова вмещающего типа в СПП с придаточным присоединительным. Вертикальные углы равны, что и требовалось доказать.С.слово вместило значение главного.

Comment: Всё, что содержится в моем ответе, в том числе терминология, соответствует  материалу из книги Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка". (от меня лично не добавлено ничего). Лингвисты предлагают разные решения в области синтаксиса, но мне такой подход кажется разумным. Кстати, нечто похожее предлагал slava1947 - у него придаточное в позиции сказуемого, а подлежащим тогда является слово "мнение" (не предложение) Понимаете, одну и ту же конструкцию можно описать в разных системах, и эти описания не исключают друг друга. . Можно провести аналогию с физикой, где свет и частица, и волна.